# Nlog IsDebugEnabled and all otheres are false

Tags: c#, logging, app-config, nlog

I'm trying to setup Nlog for my solution. I have an Solutions with multiple Projects which make an add-in for Revit.

I followed all the instructions, setup my Nlog.config file, set up an Target and a Logger.
But whenever I put a breakpoint on my Logger, all my IsEnabled messages are set to false.[image]

My Nlog.Config is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="LoggerForBaseReference" fileName="C:\temp\${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="AppLogRule" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LoggerForBaseReference" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then in my Main Class I Make the logger :

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.GetLogger("AppLogRule");
```

And Log the info I need, for example like this:

```
log.Info("OnStartup Initialized");
```

I tried Log4Net before and had exactly the same issues, and I'm really confused about it.
Why isn't it logging, and what am I not seeing?

EDIT :
When I add this to the Main, it does write a .txt file, however I still can't write my own logfile

```
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = "C:\\Temp\\NLog.Internal.txt";
```

Comment: Do you have the same effect if you (just for an experiment) use `<logger name="*" ...` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same effect yes

Comment: In that case, I'd activate internal logging and see if there is something there. If it (internal log) does not get activated, then it's pretty obvious that your config is not being picked up.

Comment: I made an edit at the post, I pasted some code from logging troubleshooting Nlog in the main to activate internal loggin like you suggested, and this does write to a .txt file. so now I really don't know what to do

Comment: Is there somewhere a second NLog config file or do you edit the configuration in code?

Comment: In `LogManager.Configuration` you could inspect the config with the debugger

Comment: I added the line `LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(@".\\NLog.config");` and now it works.. Not sure why I have to explicitly tell hem where to find the `.config` file